# Images disappear from the ListView in WPF after an action

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, listbox

Images load correctly to the listview, but whenever I click on the listview and change the SelectedItem, the images dissapear. I can see the elements and do everything with them, but they are a simple row and the image itself is not in the row.
This is the XAML for the ListView

```
<ListView Name="testLB" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="393" Margin="627,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="244" SelectionChanged="testLB_SelectionChanged"/>
```

And this is part of my ViewModel.

```
public ObservableCollection<Image> Images { get; private set; }
    public Image SelectedImage { get => selectedImage;
        set {
            this.selectedImage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedImage");
        } }

    private Image selectedImage;
```

Comment: why do you have UI elements `Image` in your view model? you didn't provide a complete and verifiable example, but I think incorrect usage of Image is a big part of a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image` is a subclass of UIElement, and should hence not be used as item type in a view model.

Use `ImageSource` instead (and add e.g. BitmapImages or BitmapFrames to your collection):

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { get; private set; }

public ImageSource SelectedImage { ... }
```

Then make your ListView's ItemTemplate contain an Image element:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}" ...>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you! Never would've guessed that this may cause problem like this. It works flawlessly now.